# Implement my own css encapsulation / scooped

Tags: javascript, css, encapsulation

I have an HTML that I inject to the DOM and coming from the server.
The issue is that it's and includes a `<style>` tag and I need to **preserve the style but prevent it from effect my whole site**. something like *scoped* CSS in Vue or *encapsulation* in Angular.

example for simplicity:https://codepen.io/nemo369/pen/BaoPprw

EDIT: 
1) the HTML is safe 
2) cannot be an IFRAME hence need to be reactive

Comment: The simplest option is put that content into a div and apply the style in your style sheet to that div via its class/id. Like you would any other content.

Comment: HTML injection is itself very dangerous. It would really be best to see if you can change your client/server solution to achieve the same thing but through a different kind of interchange.

Comment: Load it into `<iframe>`?